# Chrome reporting html5 cache manifest mime type incorrectly

Tags: html, .htaccess, mime-types, offline-caching, application-cache

I'm trying to set up a cache manifest for a site and am having little luck. A demo page is here: http://www.matthewlehner.ca

The HTML I'm using has this structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="manifest.appcache">
</html>
```

.htaccess in the root folder has the following entry:

```
AddType text/cache-manifest appcache
AddType text/cache-manifest .appcache
```

Response from `curl -I http://www.matthewlehner.ca/manifest.appcache'

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 11 Sep 2011 00:04:30 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Sat, 10 Sep 2011 07:53:30 GMT
ETag: "18a84003-32-4ac9196f95280"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 50
Content-Type: text/cache-manifest
```

But Chrome dev on OS X 10.6 is reporting the following error:

```
Application Cache Error event: Invalid manifest mime type (text/plain) http://www.matthewlehner.ca/manifest.appcache
```

Clearly this is not the case, but how do I fix this? Is it a Chrome, .htaccess, or hosting issue?

Comment: The link you gave works for me...

Comment: The application cache manifest works?

Comment: Yeah! Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest http://www.matthewlehner.ca/manifest.appcache
Application Cache Checking event
Application Cache NoUpdate event This is after the second load.

Comment: What browser/os are you on? Maybe it's a caching issue with my Chrome.

Comment: Google Chrome 13.0.782.215 on Fedora 15.

Comment: Ugh. Inconsistencies. It's working in Safari and FF. I'm just going to assume this works. Thanks!

Comment: Cool! Try clearing your cache or something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was getting the same Chrome error because my doctype was DOCTYPE! instead of !DOCTYPE.  Chrome is probably being stricter somehow in parsing your HTML than other browsers; try pasting your code into http://validator.w3.org. Or maybe try the following line alone in your .htaccess file.

```
AddType text/cache-manifest appcache manifest
```

For ease of testing refresh chrome://appcache-internals whenever you refresh http://www.matthewlehner.ca