# Application cache in HTML5 not working:

Tags: html

I'm newbie to HTML 5 Application storage. Im trying a sample to test the offline storage. I have few questions. Please help.

Files used:

**index.html**

```
<html manifest="demo.manifest"> 
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" ></script>
</head> 
<body> 
<h1>some text</h1> 
<p>Some text.</p> 
</body> 
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
body{background-color: #333;}
h1{color: #c94054;}
p{color: #fff;}
```

**demo.manifest**

```
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:
style.css
index.html
```

I know that demo.manifest MIME type has to be set to text/cache-manifest and this has to be done in the *.htaccess file. I'm using apache tomcat 6.0 server on a windows environment. I'm not able to find this file inside the server. So, I created one (test.htaccess) in the root directory of my project (which is being developed on eclipse helios) that is, in d:/eclipse-workspace/ProjectName/ and my file looks like below:

**test.htaccess**

```
AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest
```

But application cache does not work when I stop the server and tried to access it as below:

```
http://localhost:8081/ProjectName/index.html
```

Please let me know what have I done wrong with this...Also, Is there a way to debug application cache

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On a Tomcat server the MIME types are configured via the default web.xml file, `conf/web.xml`

Towards the end of that file you'll find a bunch of defined MIME types.  You have to add

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>manifest</extension>
    <mime-type>text/cache-manifest</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

as the equivalent of what you'd put in .htaccess as used by Apache and other servers.

Comment: Hi..Thanks for the information. I had done this and still I get the below error in Google Chrome error log (opened the browser log by ctrl+shift+J) "Application Cache Error event: Invalid manifest mime type ()"

Comment: @user1475068 first of all check with the Chrome developer tools - Network tab what exactly gets transfered (esp. the mime type of course).  Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375514/chrome-reporting-html5-cache-manifest-mime-type-incorrectly as I think it's a related issue.  Maybe a stupid question, did you restart Tomcat after adding the MIME type to its central web.xml?

Comment: Hi...I checked in the Network tab and I'm able to see the .css, .html and .js file but not my .manifest file. I had restarted the server as well before testing it. Also, in the post which you had said, the error message shows "text/plain" inside the brackets but in mine its just empty. What would be the correct location of the .htaccess file in windows. Do i have to refer this file elsewhere? Please help....

Comment: Hi..Finally, I had got this working. I changed the extension of the cache manifest file from .manifest to .appcache and now its working fine. Thanks for your help and suggestions.

Comment: @user1475068 glad I could help you solve your problem, good luck with your project!

Comment: ALTERNATIVELY: We can also modify only our own app's web.xml to have the same <mime-mapping> syntax. Therefore, don't have to modify the web server default conf/web,xml. I did it just that and it works ok.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Everything looked right: paths were correct, the manifest was in my project and I could manually browse to it, MIME type was set. It simply wasn't attempting to get this file from my HTML. The problem was I hadn't included the required line at the beginning of the manifest:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
```

Not having this was causing the browser to just silently ignore the manifest tag.